# Transparent Text Colour Change

Tags: color

I imported a psd format image (with transparency) file into blender. I want to now be able to manipulate the text colour to become red. Currently the surrounding outline colour of text only gets changed but the text colour itself remains white. Here is a screenshot of the shading node setup:[image]

[image: Fixed as per Brockmann's advice]

Comment: The alpha should stay the same right? If so, remove the *HSV* node and just replace your *Saturation* node by the *HSV* node used to "correct" the alpha.

Comment: Yep that worked. I think I also had the Emissions to bright and was affecting the look of it. I just darkened the Emissions and it really brought out the red. Cheers.